What is the number of essentially different solutions for a 3Doku?
The 3Doku is a Sudoku-like puzzle with blocks of 4×4 cells on the faces of a cube. Instead of columns and rows, it has bands of cells that loop around the cube.
It has me wondering how many essentially different solutions there are for a 3Doku.



Essentially Different Solutions




We can number the first block of an n×n sudoku from 1 to n², so 1 to 9 for a regular sudoku. All solutions we can find for that are essentially the same as when we swap the 2 and the 4. We get the same solutions, but just with the 2 and the 4 swapped. Other possible permutations are swapping entire columns or rows. So out of the 6,670,903,752,021,072,936,960 possible valid sudoku solutions, only 5,472,730,538 are essentially different. All the others can be constructed through permutations.



Has any work been done on this?

Not sure where I'd find research on this if it exists,  but the symmetries of the grid are permutations of the digits (16!), permutations of the bands in all three dimensions (4!³) and the symmetries of the cube (48, assuming they can't all be simulated by the other symmetries), for a total cardinality of 13,883,359,075,762,176,000.
